# Why does this scheme function run correctly then produce an "illegal function" error?

Tags: scheme

I'm attempting to write a scheme function that prints each entry of a list on a new line. This function and sample input works as expected, then gives an "illegal function" error and exits. I'm using tinyscheme from the debian repos.

```
(define print-list
  (lambda (l)
    (if (null? l)
      (display "done\n")
      (  
         (display (car l))  
         (newline)  
         (print-list (cdr l))  
      )
    )
  )
)
(print-list '(1 2 3 4 5) )
```

Comment: Should be `(begin  (display (car l)) ...`

Comment: You have a form `(operator operand operand)` in your code. It's saying the evaluation of `(display (car l))`, which is in the operator position, does not amount to a procedure after evaluation. You may create procedures that takes arguments and that returns procedures which can be used just like this so the structure isn't an error.

Answer (score 5):

A parenthesis followed by an expression means function application.

```
(expr1 expr2 ...)
```

Means evaluate `expr1`, `expr2`, .... Then apply the result of `expr1` to the result of `expr2` ... . If the result of `expr1` is not a function, then you'll see the "illegal function" error.

The fix is as leppie states to add a `begin`:

```
(define print-list
  (lambda (l)
    (if (null? l)
      (display "done\n")
      (begin  
         (display (car l))  
         (newline)  
         (print-list (cdr l))))))
(print-list '(1 2 3 4 5) )
```

Here
    (begin expr1 expr2 ....)
means evalute `expr1`, `expr2`, ... in order. Finally return the value of the last expression.

Answer (score 2):

### Block Structure

In scheme, the branches of the `if` special form do not have an implicit [block structure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_%28programming%29).  As Soegaard suggests, `begin` may be used. Or you can use `cond` to create a block—in which case, expanding to more than two branches comes along for free.

```
(define (print-list a-list)
  (cond ((null? a-list)(display "done\n"))
    (else
     (display (car a-list))
     (newline)
     (print-list (cdr a-list)))))
```

### Problem with Return Type

Note that `print-list` is problematic because it returns...well something undefined. For example in MIT Scheme:

```
1 ]=> (print-list '(a b c))
a
b
c
done
;Unspecified return value
```

Or in Gauche Scheme:

```
gosh> (print-list '(a b c))
a
b
c
done
#<undef>
```

While in Racket's implementation of R5RS the return value is not printed.

```
> (print-list '(a b c))
a
b
c
done
```

### Returning a Value

One common approach to signalling the end of a series of side effects is to return a value. `null` is one possibility. A symbol is another.

```
(define (print-list a-list)
  (cond ((null? a-list) 'done) ; changed this line.
    (else
     (display (car a-list))
     (newline)
     (print-list (cdr a-list)))))
```

Calling it now will in a Scheme REPL removes the problematic return value:

```
gosh> (print-list '(a b c))
a
b
c
done
```

Comment: *"Racket's implementation of R5RS the return value is not printed"*. It's just that the REPL supresses `#<void>`. However it is a value so if you evaluate `(list (print-list '(a b c)))` you get `(#<void>)` since it's not `eq?` `#<void>`.

Comment: @Sylwester R5RS doesn't recognize `void` or `<void>` as defined values. It does not recognize `#<void>` as valid syntax. This is true of Racket's implementation. R5RS does not define undefined types. If a person pines for C, this is a good thing. For other people it looks like a source of bugs.

Comment: R5RS uses the term undefined value as a placeholder for something not important to the spec. I've seen implementations that actually uses useful values and it's ok since any value is allowed. `#<void>` is not valid syntax but it is the representation of all undefined values in PLT-R5RS.

Comment: @Sylwester Typically when a language specification leaves something undefined it's because exiting implementations do it differently and the implementors cannot or willnot agree on a defined behavior. That doesn't mean the undefined thing is not important. Because relying on undefined behavior is a not uncommon source of bugs, it can in fact be rather important from a software engineering standpoint. That PLT-R5RS deals with it with smoothly doesn't mean another implementation can't reformat the hard-drive. Undefined is "Undefined" and there be dragons.